# pass object from controller to view in asp.net MVC and call object methods in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I create an object of class in controller and I pass it by viewData,viewBag,viewModel. I want to call object methods in view and display the results in it I write call methods in script in view file, but the code not executed , I dont know where is the error so 
I try the following code

my code in controller

```
public ActionResult Categorized()

{ var x=new PICWeb.Models.MobileClass(); return View(x); }
```

and my code in view file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var test = model.getCategories(); </script>
```

and tried the following code

```
public ActionResult Categorized()

{ var x=new PICWeb.Models.MobileClass(); ViewData["ser"]=x; ViewBag.ser=x; return View(); }
```

and in view

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var test1=@ViewBag.ser;

    var test2=@viewData["ser"];

    var res=test1.getCategories();

    var res2=test2.getCategories()

    </script> 

                                                                                   so where is the problem , can you help me
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass object from controller to view in asp.net MVC and call object member in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311390/pass-object-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc-and-call-object-member-in-vie)

Comment: Please do not create another question where you are asking the same thing. I suggest that you edit your previous question and delete this one.

Comment: @rana are you simply trying to get data from the controller to the view?  If yes then state this in the question and we could help you.  As it stands it's very difficult to understand what it is you are asking

Answer (score 1):

I really advice you to follow this tutorials before starting to program something from scratch in MVC:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

*See how you can simply pass the model to a **strongly typed view** and access its properties and methods.*

@EDIT: You're trying to run a model method in a javascript function created on a view. That's the problem. If you really want that content run the method before and pass the result to the view or you could and should use jquery ajax calls to run async method calls.

Comment: It's still a little unclear this is what Rana is trying to get to but good on you for trying

Comment: Im not shure it is either but we can see that shes passing the content with View bad/data instead of having a strongly type view and that is one of the reasons why shes having problems. I would say it is a partial answer for a multi problem question xD

Comment: Yeah, I think going through the tutorial would really be the correct answer here

Comment: thanks for your response, I made many asp.net mvc applications , I read the tutorial earlier , ok I will explain my question , getCategories method return xmlducument value and I want to view the content of this value in view page , so there is many values to display  in view page , so I cant pass each one of them from controller to view page

Comment: See my edit. You should use JQuery Ajax and call that method storing the result on a div. You can either display the div from start or inject it with jquery